# Foreach overwrites previous records in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, array-push

I have a multidimensional array, and I want to show this array in tabular form like

```
+------+-----+--------+-------+-------+
| Name | red | yellow | green | white |
+------+-----+--------+-------+-------+
| abc  |   8 |      2 |     4 |     0 |
| xyz  |   2 |      8 |     0 |     0 |
+------+-----+--------+-------+-------+
```

The following is the array that I've

```
[0] => array(
        'label'=> 'red',
        [value] => Array
        (
                [0] => array
                (
                        [count] => 47
                        [firstname] => Syst

                )
                [1] => array
                (
                        [count] => 2
                        [firstname] => xyz
                )

                [2] => array
                (
                        [count] => 8
                        [firstname] => abc
                )
)
[1] => array(
        'label'=> 'yellow',
        [value] => Array
        (
                [0] => array
                (
                        [count] => 4
                        [firstname] => dim
                )
                [1] => array
                (
                        [count] => 2
                        [firstname] => abc
                )
                [2] => array
                (
                        [count] => 8
                        [firstname] => xyz
                )
        )
```

and so on
I have tired below code but I don't know whats the problem with code.

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    echo '<th>'.$row->label.'</th></tr>';
    $i = 1;
    $final = [];
    foreach($row->value as $v){
        $temp = [];
        $temp[$v->firstname.' '.$v->lastname] = [];
        $output = findKey($final, $v->firstname.' '.$v->lastname);
        if($output){
            $temp[$v->firstname.' '.$v->lastname]['count'] = $v->count ;
            $temp[$v->firstname.' '.$v->lastname][$row->label.'_'.$row->color] =  $v->count ;
        }
        array_push($final,$temp);
    }
}
print_r($rows); //die;
```

Comment: this line is wrong `echo '<th>'.$row->label.'</th></tr>';` ~ it will add a closing `tr` tag for every iteration through the loop and will throw any formatting out of alignment

Comment: The `print_r` output you provide has been manually manipulated and could not have come from `print_r`. Please make sure to provide the array as you have it, otherwise the solution  will not be what you need.

Comment: You use `->` notation, but your data shows no objects, only arrays. Could you provide the error messages you get?

Comment: I have convert object to array $arr = array();
   $arr = objToArray($rows, $arr);
   $finalArr = array();

   foreach($arr as $newArr){
    $i=1;
    foreach($newArr['value'] as $valueArr){
     $temp = array();
     $name = $valueArr['firstname'].' '.$valueArr['lastname'];
     $temp[$name]['count_'.$i] = $valueArr['count'];
     echo $name;
     print_r($finalArr);
     if(multiKeyExists($finalArr,$name)){
      $temp[$name]['count_'.$i] = $valueArr['count'];
     }
     $i++;
     array_push($finalArr,$temp);

    }
   } but still it not working for me

Comment: What is not working, what error message you get, what output is wrong? Can you be more specific? Please add this information in the question, because in comments it is almost unreadable.

Comment: Where do you get your data from? From a database  query? If that is the case, please provide the query, because it is **much** more efficient to make the query output what you want then to manipulate the query's output in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print_r` output you have provided is not consistent -- it has been manipulated to add the label keys. print_r would have output them as `[label]`, not as `"label"`, also, `print_r` would not have output a comma at the end of the same line.

So, with the risk that the solution will not work, because you have not provided a correct array, I provide here a solution based on the following array:

```
$finalArr = 
array(
    array(
        'label' => 'red',
        'value' => Array (
                array ("count" => 47, "firstname" => 'Syst'),
                array ("count" => 2, "firstname" => 'xyz'),
                array ("count" => 8, "firstname" => 'abc')
        )
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'yellow',
        "value" => Array (
                array ("count" => 4, "firstname" => 'dim'),
                array ("count" => 2, "firstname" => 'abc'),
                array ("count" => 8, "firstname" => 'xyz')
        )
    )
);
```

Then the solution could be this:

```
// collect unique list of "firstname" values
$rowHeaders = array();
foreach($finalArr as $column) {
    $rowHeaders = array_merge($rowHeaders, array_column($column["value"], "firstname"));
}
$rowHeaders = array_unique($rowHeaders);
usort($rowHeaders, 'strcasecmp');

// get column headers
$colHeaders = array_column($finalArr, "label");

// create matrix: first column
$matrix = array(array_merge(array("Name"), $colHeaders));
foreach($rowHeaders as $firstname) {
    $matrix[] = array($firstname);
}
// ... and colour columns:
foreach($finalArr as $colIndex => $column) {
    $names = array_column($column["value"], "firstname");
    foreach ($rowHeaders as $rowIndex => $name) {
        $matrix[$rowIndex+1][] = in_array($name, $names) ? $column["value"][array_search($name, $names)]["count"] : 0;
    }
}

// convert matrix into HTML table
$html = "";
$td = "th";
foreach ($matrix as $row) {
    $html .= "<tr><$td>" . implode("</$td><$td>", $row) . "</$td></tr>\n"; 
    $td = "td";
}
$html = "<table border=1>\n$html</table>";

// output html:
echo $html;
```

The output is:

```
<table border=1>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>red</th><th>yellow</th></tr>
<tr><td>abc</td><td>8</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>dim</td><td>0</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Syst</td><td>47</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>xyz</td><td>2</td><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

Which in a browser renders as:

[image: table output]

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) But I need red,yellow as column name and firstname under names like 
Name red yellow green white
abc      8    2         4       0
dim      2    8         0       0
sys      1    0          8      45
xyz      7    2          0      5

Comment: OK, adapted answer to have rows/columns switched to what I had presented before.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize `$final` array outside of first loop. like below..

```
    $final = [];

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        echo '<th>'.$row->label.'</th></tr>';
        $i = 1;    
        foreach($row->value as $v){
            $temp = [];
            $temp[$v->firstname.' '.$v->lastname] = [];
            $output = findKey($final, $v->firstname.' '.$v->lastname);
            if($output){
                $temp[$v->firstname.' '.$v->lastname]['count'] = $v->count ;
                $temp[$v->firstname.' '.$v->lastname][$row->label.'_'.$row->color] =  $v->count ;
            }
            array_push($final,$temp);
        }
    }
    print_r($rows); //die;
```

Comment: so still now $final array is overwriting previous values?